# Why is Chrony taking over network time sync responsibilities?

Tags: time, ntp

I am wondering why is Chrony replacing NTPd as the default component for network time sync.

What is the advantage, and ideally, was there a discussion of pros-and-cons somewhere I can read for my education?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See bug report [LP:1744072](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chrony/+bug/1744072):

> 2. Rationale:
>
>    2.1 NTP in general is needed quite a lot, but we want to exchange ntpd
>       which is the current implementation in main with chrony for 18.04.
>
>    2.2 Security: chrony was considered easier to be maintained easier in
>       terms of security and provide a more modern ntp experience as well.
>
>    2.3 Efficiency: Furthermore several cloud people seem to be interested to
>       change to chrony in the guests for its lower memoy/cpu footprint
>       (efficiency I guess).
>
>    2.4 related to this MIR 6 years ago this is the same but for Fedora.
>      See: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ChronyDefaultNTP
>      IIRC some limitations that were present have been eliminated since, so
>      it is even better than it was back then.
>
>    2.5 In general one has to realize that in a systemd-timesync world
>      ntp/chrony are mostly for the "serving" portion of an ntp service, and
>      not so much about the client (unless you the better accuracy vs
>      timesyncd is needed).